# Having trouble with the substitution method.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to evaluate the integral:

[image]

I see that with u being equal to $4x$ I will get that $du/dx$ will equal $4$ and lead to $du=4dx$. However I am stuck when I plug in the u values to get $\sec u\cos u\,du$. The problem states to use the subsitution method but it looks like I will have to use the product rule because of $\sec u\cos u\,du$. Is there a way to evaluate this integral without the product rule? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean $\sec u \tan u du=\frac{\sin u}{\cos^2 u}du?$

Comment: Ah sorry yes sec(u)tan(u). Is it sin(u)/cos^2(u) by definition of sec(u)tan(u)?

Comment: Use that $\sec u=1/\cos u$ and $\tan u=\sin u/\cos u.$

Comment: The easiest way is to recall that the derivative of $\sec t$ is $\sec t\tan t$. But once you are at $\frac{\sin u}{\cos^2 u}$ you can let $w=\cos u$.

Comment: Knowing your derivatives will help a lot with basic integrals. Since the derivative of $\sec(x)$ is $\tan(x)\sec(x)$ this anti-derivative is just the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u = 4x$, so $du = 4dx$, we will have $\sec(u)\tan(u)$ whose integral is $\sec(u)$. Using our substitution again, we have:

$\displaystyle\int \sec(4x)\tan(4x) \mathrm{dx} = \frac{\sec(4x)}{4} + C$

Comment: I think you meant $\tan(4x)$ not $\cos(4x)$

Comment: Why is it that sec(u) is the integral of sec(u)tan(u)?

Comment: The derivative of $\sec(u)$ is $\sec(u)\tan(u)$.

Comment: We have that:

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx} \sec(x) = \frac{-(-\sin(x))}{\cos^{2}(x)} = \sec(x)\tan(x)$. Using the fact $\sec(x) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$

Comment: Oooh ok I thought I had to find the derivative of sec(4x) and tan(4x) when what I really have to look for is the term that gives you sec(4x)tan(4x). thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the change of variable $u = \cos 4x, du = -4 \sin 4x \, dx$ instead.

then $$\int \sec 4x \tan 4x \, dx = \int \frac{\sin 4x}{\cos^2 4x} \, dx
\to -\frac 14\int \frac{du}{u^2} = \frac{1}{4u} = \frac 14\sec4x + C$$